# How can we put the total list in order based upon single item in that list?

Tags: vb.net

I am working on vb.net windows8 mobile application in that application i am saving item in the list help me to put this list in order based upon single item in that list.

code :

```
'Job Custom Event Details............... 
Dim JobEventAllDetails As New List(Of EventDetails)
JobEventAllDetails = JobEventDetails.EventDetailsList.ToList()
```

List order:

```
(New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(Of Agility_Alerts.TrackingServiceReference.EventDetails)(JobEventAllDetails)).Items(0).Seq 0

(New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(Of Agility_Alerts.TrackingServiceReference.EventDetails)(JobEventAllDetails)).Items(2).Seq 300

(New System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(Of Agility_Alerts.TrackingServiceReference.EventDetails)(JobEventAllDetails)).Items(1).Seq 200
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in a VB Unit test project

```
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

<TestClass()> Public Class UnitTest1
  <TestMethod()> Public Sub TestMethod1()

    Dim eventDetailsList As New List(Of EventDetails) From { _
        New EventDetails With {.Seq = 0, .SomeData = ""}, _
        New EventDetails With {.Seq = 300, .SomeData = ""}, _
        New EventDetails With {.Seq = 200, .SomeData = ""}}

    Dim JobeventDetails As New JobEventDetailsList With {.EventDetailsList = eventdetailslist}

    Dim JobEventAllDetails = JobeventDetails.EventDetailsList.OrderBy(Function(j) j.Seq).ToList
    For Each job In JobEventAllDetails
        Console.WriteLine(job.Seq)
    Next
  End Sub
End Class

Class EventDetails
    Public Property Seq As Integer
    Public SomeData As String
End Class
Class JobEventDetailsList
    Public EventDetailsList As List(Of EventDetails)
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean sorting a list, by a property... You can use the OrderBy function

```
Dim list2 = list.OrderBy(Function(k) k.field2)
```